# Caracteres especiales no se muestran usando UTF-8

Tags: php, html

Buenas,

Estoy teniendo problemas con la codificación de texto, al importar de la base de datos los caracteres como "ñ" o cualquier tilde "á, é..." se muestran con un interrogante.

En el header tengo agregado el siguiente código:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Pero aún así sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

He probado a hacerlo de forma manual pero tampoco me da resultado.

```
function quita_acentos_enyes($texto) {
$devolver = str_replace("&aacute;", "á", $texto);
$texto = str_replace("&eacute;", "é", $texto);
$texto = str_replace("&iacute;", "í", $texto);
$texto = str_replace("&oacute;", "ó", $texto);
$texto = str_replace("&uacute;", "ú", $texto);
$texto = str_replace("&ntilde;", "ñ", $texto);

return $texto;
}
```

Tengo también problemas con signos de interrogación y algún que otro caracter especial más.

Comment: Este problema ya se planteó aquí y también la solución: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510

Comment: Ya usaste **html_entity_decode();**?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz no lo había usado, pero lo acabo de probar y me sigue dando el mismo resultado. En sí la información en la base de datos incluye acentos y eñes, lo único que se me ocurre es que antes de introducir la información en la base de datos modificar esos caracteres por su correspondiente en html.

Comment: Dices que estás importando, haces una carga manual? usas código php, qué procedimiento utilizas? Depende de lo que hagas para dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: **<meta charset="utf-8">** ?

Comment: De qué forma estás realizando la conexión a la base de datos? MySQL, MySQLi, PDO?